# Access inner child page's public variable within the parent page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Can you tell me how to access inner child page's public variable within the parent page? i.e. I need to access this variable `offlineArticlesCount`.

**Note:** All 3 below components have their own `modules`.

*myPage.html* - Parent page

```
 <picks *ngFor="let pick of pickData" [data]="pick"></picks>
 <p>{{instance.offlineArticlesCount}}</p> //How to do this?
```

*myPage.ts*

```
 @ViewChild(DownloadOfflineArticleComponent) instance: DownloadOfflineArticleComponent;
```

*picks.html*

```
<download-offline-article [data]="data" (onDownloadOfflineArticle)="downloadOfflineArticle($event)"></download-offline-article>
```

*download-offline-article.ts* - Inner child componet

```
export class DownloadOfflineArticleComponent {
   offlineArticlesCount: number = 0;
   constructor(){} 

downloadOfflineArticle() {
    this.articleService.downloadOfflineArticle(this.data.id)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.onDownloadOfflineArticle.emit(true);

        this.localCacheService.clearMyLibraryPageCacheGroup().then(() => {
          this.getAllMyPurchasedOfflineArticles().subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.offlineArticlesCount = res.count;//here is the place where it updates
          },
            error => { },
            () => { });
        });
      },
      error => { },
      () => { });
  }
    }
```

Comment: Have you already tried with ViewChild like this: `@ViewChild(DownloadOfflineArticleComponent) instance: DownloadOfflineArticleComponent;` and then in the view just use `{{ instance?. offlineArticlesCount}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers are right, it just depends on where do you want to use that property from the child component.

**If you just want to show it in the view**, you could use a *template reference variable*

```
<picks *ngFor="let pick of pickData" [data]="pick"></picks>
<p>{{ offlineArticle.offlineArticlesCount }}</p>
<download-offline-article #offlineArticle ..."></download-offline-article>
```

That way you don't create an instance of the child component in your parent's component code.

**If you want to use that property in your component code**, the best way to do it would be by using `ViewChild` to get the instance of the child component:

```
// Parent component code...

@ViewChild(DownloadOfflineArticleComponent) childComponent: DownloadOfflineArticleComponent;
```

Of course you can then use it in the view like this:

```
<!-- Your view -->
{{ childComponent?. offlineArticlesCount}}
```

**EDIT**

Since you have a more complex hierarchy of components, I think the best way to fix this issue would be by using a shared service, where you can store all the shared information. That way, you can access to that data in a more easy way from any component (or page) from your app.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Is there any error?

Comment: No errors.But it seems not updating the UI.I can debug it and that variable as a value.But UI doesn't show that.Please see the latest code Where I have added.

Comment: Does it show the 0 in the view the first time, or is it not being even initialized?

Comment: Your first method won't work for me.Because I have an inner child.i.e. this `download-offline-article` component is inside this `picks` component.Please see my code.

Comment: No `0` even.Nothing.

Comment: Oh, I know understand the hierarchy. Since it seems a complex scenario because of the nested components, would it be a valid option to use a shared service to store the `offlineArticlesCount` property (and any other data that needs to be shared)?. I'm asking just because you may face some issues related to how the change detection mechanism works because of that nested components hierachy. Otherwise, I guess the best way to fix this, would be to add some public getters that return that property, and use `@Output` to send it to the parents component...

Comment: Hmm..Any simple example according to my components hierarchy, please?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a simple plunker? That way I can try a few things by using some code similar to yours

Comment: I think simple `provider` or `service` will do my job no?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant in _Since it seems a complex scenario because of the nested components, would it be a valid option to use a shared service to store the offlineArticlesCount property (and any other data that needs to be shared)?_ You can use that service to store the shared data, and then access it from any component in a more simple way

Comment: I've edited the answer to include that as well. If you decide not to use a shared service, we can try a few ways to pass that value through all the components, but it would definitely be an uglier solution.

Comment: I have done like this inside the `DownloadOfflineArticleComponent` component `this.articleService.offlineArticlesCount = res.count;`.Now which event should I use this on `myPage.ts` file.Hence there is no event occuring on at `myPage.ts` page hence all are on same page.Your thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you inject the `articleService` in the constructor of the parent page, and then use `{{ articleService.offlineArticlesCount }}` in the view?

Comment: I have never used it like that before.But it's working.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yeah, since it's just a property, every time a change occurs Angular will read the value from the service. Glad to hear that it finally worked :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just One line :

```
@ViewChild(DownloadOfflineArticleComponent) childComp: DownloadOfflineArticleComponent;
```

And then access all the public properties with `{{ childComp?.offlineArticlesCount }}`

Comment: This is not working due to complex components hierarchy.Please see my code.

Comment: @Sampath , Okay you have changed the code a bit , is it possible to create the plunker of it , it would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

After you've edited your question to clarify your components hierarchy, I think the best way to solve your problem is to use a shared service to share data betwen your components:

```
// Create the shared service like below:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    private articleCountSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});    

    setArticleCount(count: any): void {
        this.articleCountSubject.next(count);
    }
    getArticleCount(): Observable<any> {
        return this.articleCountSubject.asObservable();
    }
}

// myPage.ts:

constructor(private sharedService: SharedService){}
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.getArticleCount().subscribe(count=> {
        this.offlineArticlesCount = count;
    });
}

// myPage.html:

<picks *ngFor="let pick of pickData" [data]="pick"></picks>
<p> {{offlineArticlesCount }} </p>

// download-offline-article.ts:

//...
this.getAllMyPurchasedOfflineArticles().subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.sharedService.setArticleCount(res.count);
},
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use template reference variable:

```
<picks *ngFor="let pick of pickData" [data]="pick"></picks>
<p>{{ offlineArticle.offlineArticlesCount }}</p>
<download-offline-article #offlineArticle [data]="data" (onDownloadOfflineArticle)="downloadOfflineArticle($event)"></download-offline-article>
```

Comment: My components hierarchy is not like this.Please see my code.

Comment: In this case, you should use a service to share data betwen your components